# IntegrityError exception in DeleteView CBV

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm back with more Django Class Based View questions.  I have an "extended" `user` model in the form of a "profile" model.  The profile model is using CBVs to implement CRUD functionality but the `DeleteView` always generates `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` IntegrityError exception.  I know what that should mean but I am not sure why I am getting that exception.

I have the built-in Django `user` model plus an "account adaptor" and my custom `Profile` model.  The account adaptor just sets the signup email address as the username:

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
        Log.add("")
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.username = data['email']  # username not in use
        user.email = data['email']
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data['password1'])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()

        self.populate_username(request, user)

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

The `Profile` model has a `OneToOneField` to attach a profile instance to a user.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

The `DeleteView` CBV is:

```
@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class Delete(DeleteView):
    pk_url_kwarg = "account_number"
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = "/accounts/logout.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            profile = self.model.objects.get(account_number=self.kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg])

            user = User.objects.get(pk=profile.user.pk)
            user.delete()

            messages.success(request, "The user is deleted")
            my_render = render(request, self.success_url)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "User does not exist")
            my_render = render(request, self.success_url)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, "DB IntegrityError")
            my_render = render(request, self.success_url)

        return my_render
```

In the `Delete.get` method I can put a breakpoint on the `user.delete()` line and I can see that the `profile` and `user` objects are what I think they should be.  I try to delete the user object and I get the IntegrityError exception listed above.

The stack-trace looks like:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Members/Profile/d83622e4-4816-42a4-8419-2fd389c7e3fd/delete?csrfmiddlewaretoken=y3W0ze1SfN50Mx3eymEZQQPd21u5wjf0tHvRZM0PggLX12mdAgdEGUkw3lw2KnKn

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'auditlog',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'Members.apps.MembersConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  32.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/MyProject/MyApp\Members\views\profile.py" in get
  103.             user.delete()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in delete
  891.         return collector.delete()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py" in delete
  307.                             sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __exit__
  212.                         connection.commit()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in commit
  261.         self._commit()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /Members/Profile/d83622e4-4819-42d4-8419-2fd389c7e3fd/delete
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I think my problem is with `sqlite3`.  My DB backend is sqlite3.  I have just discovered that the Django migrations that create the `Profile` model table DO create a foreign key reference from the profile to the `User` model but an `on delete cascade` clause is NOT created.  The constraint Django creates looks like:

```
FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user`(`id`) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
```

I added the `on delete cascade` option by hand:

```
FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user`(`id`) on delete cascade DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
```

but the delete operation failed as above.  I dropped the `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` clause and still get the violation.

I have a sqlite gui "management" tool and just tried to delete a `user` record using that management tool and get a foreign key violation as well so this must be on the sqlite side of things.

**Edit 2**

After more investigation I see the following:  I am new to python and Django.  My Django test app is really very small and I am not doing any/many custom actions.  Using sqlite as the DB backend and doing the initial project `makemigrations` and `migrate` created the standard Django and `django-allauth` tables.  There are a few of these base tables that have `FOREIGN KEY` relationships with the `user` table.  My last survey of the DB was not extremely rigorous as it was really late last night ... but those that do reference the `user` table do not have `on delete cascade` clauses.  So, even if I fix "my" table(s) the base Django tables that reference `user` seem to be "broken" by not having the `cascade` clause.

I will file a bug report if I can figure out where to send it.

Comment: can you check other related models for `User` `User._meta.related_objects` may be there some protected field

Comment: Thanks @BearBrown.  My project is small at the moment.  I only have the `Profile` model in my code space.  I am using `django-allauth` and that certainly touches the `User` model but I have no real control over that... I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have learned something.  Django does not currently support the `on delete cascade` DB clause.  It looks like you have to implement the behaviour yourself.  I have seen posts in the email "Django Users" group about using signals for this.

I decided to try it in the `DeleteView.get()` method.

```
class Delete(DeleteView):
    pk_url_kwarg = "account_number"
    model = Profile
    # form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = "account/login.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, account_number=self.kwargs[self.pk_url_kwarg])
            user_pk = profile.user.pk
            profile.delete()

            get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_pk).delete()

            messages.success(request, "The user is deleted")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, "User does not exist")
        # except IntegrityError:
        #     messages.error(request, "DB IntegrityError")

        return render(request, self.success_url)
```

It is possible that I don't have to actually delete the profile instance but I am still testing.